# How to transform interface children's type to type[]?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I got an interface, and I want to generate an new interface by transforming it's children's type into type[]; But I cannot fulfill it. How to do this transformation?

```
interface IItem {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  c: string;
}

interface IArrayChildrenType<T> {
  // I tried this way, but it was totally incorrect
  // [key: keyof T]: Array<typeof T[key]>;
}

interface IExpected {
  a: number[];
  b: number[];
  c: string[];
}

type INewType = IArrayChildrenType<IItem>;

// expect INewType === IExpected
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. [Mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) is what you're looking for:

```
type IArrayChildrenType<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: Array<T[P]>;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKsgW2QbwFDLJwBcyIArpgEbQDcByVpF1dDCpAzmFKAOb0AvnjxgAngAcUqAIJQocMQGEAFsAA2AEygQQAFUkQAPHoB8yALy4GhANoAFZKGQBrCGID2MZHoC6pOQUxEwdfUyERcSk0ADkIAHcDaKtZeUVVDW1dJON0LHCgA)

Answer (score 0):

```
interface IItem {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  c: string;
  childrentype: [IArrayChildrenType<T>]
}

interface IArrayChildrenType<T> {

}
```

calling it

```
const IItem: item
const children: IArrayChildrenType<T>  = values[1]
item.childrentype = children
```